# how to update array of object in react state based on id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, crud

i'm new learning react. i have study case with basic operation (CRUD) in react. i create react saving app for CRUD expense or income.

i have three components i.e InputData for input data, TotalMoney for display total money,expense and income, and table for display all data.

*nb pemasukan=income,pengeluaran=expense, jumlah=amount

example data like this

```
this.state: {
    items: [
               {id:1, tipe:"pemasukan", jumlah:20000},
               {id:1, tipe:"pemasukan", jumlah:20000}
           ]
}
```

[this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a5FB.png)

the problem is when want to update data. like the image,when change the first data what changes is the data afterwards, not the first data. the second problem is when the type of the first data changes from income to expense, total money for total expenditure and total income not changed on display.

what is the best way for updating data in this study case?

this is my function to update data

```
updateItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const updatedTipe = this.state.tipe;
    const updatedJumlah = parseInt(this.state.jumlah);
    const updatedJudul = this.state.judul;
    const updatedItems = Object.assign({}, this.state.items, {
      tipe: updatedTipe,
      jumlah: updatedJumlah,
      judul: updatedJudul
    });
    console.log(updatedItems);
    const itemLists = this.state.itemLists.map(itemList =>
      itemList.id === this.state.items.id ? updatedItems : itemList
    );
    console.log(itemLists);
    this.setState({ jumlah: 0, judul: "", itemLists: itemLists });
    this.setEditing(false);
  };
```

this is declaration table in component inputdata

```
<Table
  items={items}
  itemLists={itemLists}
  editing={editing}
  editItem={this.editItem}
  tipe={tipe}
  jumlah={jumlah}
  judul={judul}
  setEditing={this.setEditing}
  deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  updateItem={this.updateItem}
/>
```

this is input value for update data

```
<tr className="rowHover">
<td>
                <select
                  className="form-control form-table"
                  name="tipe"
                  onChange={props.onChange}
                >
                  <option>Pilih</option>
                  <option value="pengeluaran">Pengeluaran</option>
                  <option value="pemasukan">Pemasukan</option>
                </select>
              </td>

              <td>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control form-table"
                  name="jumlah"
                  value={props.jumlah}
                  onChange={props.onChange}
                />
              </td>

              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-table"
                  name="judul"
                  value={props.judul}
                  onChange={props.onChange}
                />
              </td>

              <td>
                <button
                  onClick={props.updateItem}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-success buttonStyles"
                >
                  Update
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => props.setEditing(false)}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-warning buttonStyles"
                >
                  Cancel
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

this is the state

```
this.state = {
      id: null,
      judul: "",
      tipe: "",
      jumlah: 0,
      pengeluaran: 0,
      pemasukan: 0,
      totalUang: 0,
      items: {},
      itemLists: [],
      editing: false
    };
```

this is my code
https://github.com/saldhyyoga/test

Comment: Can you try to give a minimal example of the code that is not working.

Comment: The problem code is on updateItem. It's a function for handling event when click update. For more complete code please look my github code on link above.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code to see what the problem is and I found a solution that works.
You have to make 2 updates:
- the first one is persisting the id of the updated item too

```
  editItem = item => {
    this.setState({
      editing: true,
      id: item.id, // add this line
      jumlah: item.jumlah,
      tipe: item.tipe,
      judul: item.judul
    });
  };
```

- the second one is to access the edited item data based on the persisted id

```
updateItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const updatedTipe = this.state.tipe;
    const updatedJumlah = parseInt(this.state.jumlah);
    const updatedJudul = this.state.judul;
    const updatedId = this.state.id; // take edited item id
    const updatedItems = Object.assign({}, this.state.items[updatedId], { // access the information of the editem item
      tipe: updatedTipe,
      jumlah: updatedJumlah,
      judul: updatedJudul
    });
    console.log(updatedItems);
    const itemLists = this.state.itemLists
      .map(itemList =>
        itemList.id === this.state.id ? updatedItems : itemList // replace this.state.items.id with this.state.id
      );
    console.log(itemLists);
    this.setState({ jumlah: 0, judul: "", itemLists: itemLists });
    this.setEditing(false);
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hofstadter-pu7j9) is link where you can find the updated solution which is working as expected.

**Edit**
In order to fix the amounts calculation just invoke the `amount` function at the end of `updateItem` function:

```
  updateItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const updatedTipe = this.state.tipe;
    const updatedJumlah = parseInt(this.state.jumlah);
    const updatedJudul = this.state.judul;
    const updatedId = this.state.id;
    const updatedItems = Object.assign({}, this.state.items[updatedId], {
      tipe: updatedTipe,
      jumlah: updatedJumlah,
      judul: updatedJudul
    });
    console.log(updatedItems);
    const itemLists = this.state.itemLists.map(itemList =>
      itemList.id === this.state.id ? updatedItems : itemList
    );
    console.log(itemLists);
    this.setState({ jumlah: 0, judul: "", itemLists: itemLists });
    this.setEditing(false);
    this.amount(itemLists); // add this line
  };
```

You can also find the update at the same [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hofstadter-pu7j9)

Comment: it works for update judul(title) and jumlah(amount). but there's another problem,it's when the data is changed from tipe(type) from pengeluaran(expense) to pemasukan(income) is changed all type data from expense to income,
22/5000
vice versa. any ideas?

Comment: @MilanistiMerchantPreSempre I have edited my answer with the updated you need to make.